# Use XMLReader to find node and retrieve XML from current node and following children

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader

I'm trying to retrieve one specific node based on the `<id>` element from a huge XML file. I have used DOMDocument, but its not ideal since it loads the whole document first. There is around 1400 `<item>` nodes in the document. This is a simplified version of the document:

```
<main>
  <body>
    ...
    <sub>
      ...
      <items>
        ...
        <item>
          <name>Abc</name>
          ...
          <id>123</id>
            <calls>
              <call>
                <name>Monkey</name>
                <text>Monkeys r cool</text>
                ...
              </call>
              <call>
                <name>Pig</name>
                <text>Pigs too!</text>
                ...
              </call>
            </calls>
            <cones>
              <cone>
                <name>Lorem</name>
                <text>Lorem ipsum</text>
                ...
              </cone>
              <cone>
                <name>More</name>
                <text>Placeholder</text>
                ...
              </cone>
            </cones>
          <a>true</a>
        </item>
        <item>
          <name>Def</name>
          ...
          <id>456</id>
            <calls>
              <call>
                <name>aa</name>
                <text>aa</text>
                ...
              </call>
              <call>
                <name>bb</name>
                <text>bb</text>
                ...
              </call>
            </calls>
            <cones>
              <cone>
                <name>cc</name>
                <text>cc</text>
                ...
              </cone>
              <cone>
                <name>dd</name>
                <text>dd</text>
                ...
              </cone>
            </cones>
          <a>true</a>
        </item>
      </items>
    </sub>
  </body>
</main>
```

So basically I'm trying to retrieve the current node and its children's data from matching the `<id>` element. I have tried find tutorials on XMLReader, but can't seem to find that much. This is what I've tried so far:

```
$xml = new XMLReader();
$xml->open('doc.xml');

while($xml->read()) {
    if($xml->nodeType == XMLREADER::ELEMENT && $xml->localName == 'id') {
        $xml->read();
        echo $xml->value;
  }
}
```

This finds every `<id>` element, but i want to find one specific and read the data from the current node, and its children. Maybe using the example to find the node and `readInnerXml()` to get the data

I'm not an expert so any help / push to the right direction is much appreciated :D

Comment: You can use an hybrid approach with XMLReader and DOMDocument. For example you reach the first item, create a DOMNode with it (with XMLReader::expand), append it to a DOMDocument instance and check if the id is the good one. If it isn't, use XMLReader::next to jump to the next item.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte actually you do not need to attach (and remove) the node. Just expand it into a prepared document and use the context argument for Xpath calls.

Comment: @ThW: I didn't know it was possible to use XPath "outside" of the DOM tree (even using a context argument). It's indeed lighter if you don't have to append or replace the node for each item. Good Job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the `item` elements are siblings you can use `XMLReader::read()` to find the first element and `XMLReader::next()` to iterate them.

Then use `XMLReader::expand()` to load the `item` and its descendants into DOM, use Xpath to read data from it.

```
$searchForID = '123';

$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open('data:text/xml;base64,'.base64_encode(getXMLString()));

$document = new DOMDocument();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

// look for the first "item" element node
while (
  $reader->read() && $reader->localName !== 'item'
) {
  continue;
}

// iterate "item" sibling elements
while ($reader->localName === 'item') {
  // expand into DOM
  $item = $reader->expand($document);
  // if the node has a child "id" with the searched contents
  if ($xpath->evaluate("count(self::*[id = '$searchForID']) > 0", $item)) {
    var_dump(
      [
        // fetch node text content as string  
        'name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(name)', $item),
        // fetch list of "call" elements and map them
        'calls' => array_map(
          function(DOMElement $call) use ($xpath) {
            return [
              'name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(name)', $call),
              'text' => $xpath->evaluate('string(text)', $call)
            ];
          },
          iterator_to_array(
            $xpath->evaluate('calls/call', $item)
          )
        )
      ] 
    );
  }
  $reader->next('item');
}
$reader->close();
```

#### XML with namespaces

If the XML uses a namespace (like the one you linked in the comments) you will have to takes it into consideration.

For the XMLReader that means validating not just `localName` (the node name without any namespace prefix/alias) but the `namespaceURI` as well.

For DOM methods that would mean using the namespace aware methods (with the suffix NS) and registering your own alias/prefix for the Xpath expressions.

```
$searchForID = '2755';

$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open('data:text/xml;base64,'.base64_encode(getXMLString()));

// the namespace uri
$xmlns_siri = 'http://www.siri.org.uk/siri';

$document = new DOMDocument();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
// register an alias for the siri namespace 
$xpath->registerNamespace('siri', $xmlns_siri);

// look for the first "item" element node
while (
  $reader->read() && 
  (
    $reader->localName !== 'EstimatedVehicleJourney' ||
    $reader->namespaceURI !== $xmlns_siri
  )
) {
  continue;
}

// iterate "item" sibling elements
while ($reader->localName === 'EstimatedVehicleJourney') {
    // validate the namespace of the node
  if ($reader->namespaceURI === $xmlns_siri) {
    // expand into DOM
    $item = $reader->expand($document);
    // if the node has a child "VehicleRef" with the searched contents
    // note the use of the registered namespace alias
    if ($xpath->evaluate("count(self::*[siri:VehicleRef = '$searchForID']) > 0", $item)) {
      var_dump(
        [
          // fetch node text content as string  
          'name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(siri:OriginName)', $item),
          // fetch list of "call" elements and map them
          'calls' => array_map(
            function(DOMElement $call) use ($xpath) {
              return [
                'name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(siri:StopPointName)', $call),
                'reference' => $xpath->evaluate('string(siri:StopPointRef)', $call)
              ];
            },
            iterator_to_array(
              $xpath->evaluate('siri:RecordedCalls/siri:RecordedCall', $item)
            )
          )
        ] 
      );
    }
  }
  $reader->next('EstimatedVehicleJourney');
}
$reader->close();
```

Comment: It works great with the simplified xml document, but when i try to convert to the more advanced xml document I cant seem to make it work. I'm wondering if you would like to take a look :D, here is the data https://t.srd.tf/data.xml . `item` = `EstimatedVehicleJourney` and `id` = `VehicleRef`

Comment: I also see thah you encode it, but i couldnt make it work so i just used: `$reader->open('https://t.srd.tf/data.xml');`. Maybe thats what wrong

Comment: I used https://3v4l.org/pZA7L#v8.0.10 to make sure that my example source works. Using a string source allows for a fully contained test. Hence creating a data URI from the string to load the source. You don't get results because the XML uses a (default) namespace - I added an example for this.

Comment: Hi ThW, how would I find `VehicleRef` if it was under a new child element? Its now in `NEW_ELEMENT`. Could you take a look? https://t.srd.tf/data.xml . I would still want to retrieve the same information

Comment: You mean inside `count(self::*[siri:VehicleRef = '$searchForID']) > 0`? You can add it to the location path inside the condition - don't forget the namepsace alias: `count(self::*[siri:NEW_ELEMENT/siri:VehicleRef = '$searchForID']) > 0`. I suggest reading up about XPath 1.0 expressions.